# Pygame: Test for collision underneath player?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I'm working on a platformer game in which the player has a sword. I want the player to only be able to attack when there is ground underneath him (so he can't attack in the air). So I implmented this code:

```
for b in instancelist:
    for p in players:
        if b.rect.collidepoint(p.rect.centerx,p.rect.bottom+4):
            grounded=1
        else:
            grounded=0
print grounded
```

But..

```
print grounded
```

Returns zero every time.. although if I add `exit(1)` to the part where it tests for the player being on the ground, it still exits! (while grounded still equals zero)

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
import pygame,random
from collections import namedtuple
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Legend of Zelda | By Sam Tubb')
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
instancelist=[]
players=[]
enemys=[]
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
Move = namedtuple('Move', ['up', 'left', 'right'])

#load sprites
block1=pygame.image.load('block1.png').convert()

#load/init player stuffs
playersprites=[pygame.image.load('link1.png').convert(),pygame.image.load('link2.png').convert(),
pygame.image.load('link3.png').convert(),pygame.image.load('linkatk.png').convert(),pygame.image.load('linkup.png').convert()]
for s in playersprites:
    s.set_colorkey((255,0,0))
frame=0
frameplus=1
frametime=0
psprite=playersprites[frame]
max_gravity = 75
left=0
atk=0
atktime=0
grounded=0

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.sprite=playersprites[0]
        self.rect=self.sprite.get_rect(left=x,top=y)
class Player(object):
    sprite=psprite
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.sprite.get_rect(centery=y, centerx=x)
        # indicates that we are standing on the ground
        # and thus are "allowed" to jump
        self.on_ground = True
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.jump_speed = 7
        self.move_speed = 3

    def update(self, move, blocks):

        # check if we can jump 
        if move.up and self.on_ground:
            self.yvel -= self.jump_speed

        # simple left/right movement
        if move.left:
                self.xvel = -self.move_speed
        if move.right:
                self.xvel = self.move_speed

        # if in the air, fall down
        if not self.on_ground:
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # but not too fast
            if self.yvel > max_gravity: self.yvel = max_gravity

        # if no left/right movement, x speed is 0, of course
        if not (move.left or move.right):
            self.xvel = 0

        # move horizontal, and check for horizontal collisions
        self.rect.left += self.xvel
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, blocks)

        # move vertically, and check for vertical collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        self.on_ground = False;
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, blocks)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, blocks):
        # all blocks that we collide with
        for block in [blocks[i] for i in self.rect.collidelistall(blocks)]:

            # if xvel is > 0, we know our right side bumped 
            # into the left side of a block etc.
            if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = block.rect.right

            # if yvel > 0, we are falling, so if a collision happpens 
            # we know we hit the ground (remember, we seperated checking for
            # horizontal and vertical collision, so if yvel != 0, xvel is 0)
            if yvel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top+0.4
                self.on_ground = True
                self.yvel = 0
            # if yvel < 0 and a collision occurs, we bumped our head
            # on a block above us
            if yvel < 0: self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

class Block(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,sprite):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.sprite=sprite
        self.rect=self.sprite.get_rect(x=self.x,y=self.y)

x = y = 0
level = [
"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
"B                                       B",
"B                                       B",
"B               L                       B",
"B                                       B",
"B                                       B",
"B                                       B",
"B                       E               B",
"B                                       B",
"B         BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB               B",
"B        B                              B",
"B     E B                               B",
"B      B                                B",
"B     B                                 B",
"B    B                                  B",
"B   B                                   B",
"B                   E                   B",
"B                                       B",
"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
]
# build the level
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "B":
            p = Block(x,y,block1)
            instancelist.append(p)
        if col=="L":
             players.append(Player(x, y))
        if col=="E":
            enemys.append(Enemy(x,y))
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

#mainloop
while True:
    for b in instancelist:
        for p in players:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(p.rect.centerx,p.rect.bottom+4):
                grounded=1
            else:
                grounded=0
    print grounded
    #total_level_width  = len(level[0])*16
    #total_level_height = len(level)*16
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if atk==0:
        if not key[K_w]:
            if key[K_a]:
                left=1
                if frameplus==1:
                    if frame<2:
                        frameplus=0
                        frametime=5
                        frame+=1
                    else:
                        frame=0
                psprite=pygame.transform.flip(playersprites[frame],1,0)
            if key[K_d]:
                left=0
                if frameplus==1:
                    if frame<2:
                        frameplus=0
                        frametime=5
                        frame+=1
                    else:
                        frame=0
                psprite=playersprites[frame]
            if not key[K_a]:
                if not key[K_d]:
                    if left==0:
                        psprite=playersprites[0]
                    else:
                        psprite=pygame.transform.flip(playersprites[0],1,0)
        else:
            if left==0:
                psprite=playersprites[4]
            else:
                psprite=pygame.transform.flip(playersprites[4],1,0)
    if key[K_SPACE]:
        if atk==0:
            atk=1
            atktime=15
            if left==0:
                psprite=playersprites[3]
                p.rect.right+=4
            else:
                psprite=pygame.transform.flip(playersprites[3],1,0)
                p.rect.right-=16
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit(1)
    for inst in instancelist:
        screen.blit(inst.sprite,inst.rect)
    for p in players:
        if atk==0:
            p.rect=psprite.get_rect(x=p.rect.left,y=p.rect.top)
            move = Move(key[K_w], key[K_a], key[K_d])
            p.update(move, instancelist)
        #scrolling
        if p.rect.right>=500:
            for inst in instancelist:
                inst.rect.left-=4
            for e in enemys:
                e.rect.left-=4
            p.rect.left-=4
        if p.rect.left<=140:
            for inst in instancelist:
                inst.rect.left+=4
            for e in enemys:
                e.rect.left+=4
            p.rect.left+=4
        if p.rect.top<=80:
            for inst in instancelist:
                inst.rect.top+=4
            for e in enemys:
                e.rect.top+=4
            p.rect.top+=4
        if p.rect.bottom>300:
            for inst in instancelist:
                inst.rect.bottom-=4
            for e in enemys:
                e.rect.bottom-=4
            p.rect.bottom-=4


        for b in instancelist:
            if p.rect.colliderect(b.rect):
                p.ground=1
        screen.blit(psprite,p.rect)

        for e in enemys:
            if atk==1:
                if left==0:
                    if p.rect.left<e.rect.left:
                        if p.rect.colliderect(e.rect):
                            enemys.remove(e)
                else:
                    if p.rect.right>e.rect.right:
                        if p.rect.colliderect(e.rect):
                            enemys.remove(e)
            screen.blit(e.sprite,e.rect)

    #timers
    if frametime>0:
        frametime-=1
    else:
        frameplus=1

    if atktime>0:
        atktime-=1
    else:
        if atk==1:
            if left==1:
                p.rect.right+=16
            else:
                p.rect.right-=4
        atktime=0
        atk=0

    p.rect=psprite.get_rect(x=p.rect.left,y=p.rect.top)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ((255,0,0)), p.rect, 1)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Could someone please lend a hand? :)

Comment: When your loops end, the value of `grounded` will be set to the result of the last `collidepoint` check that was performed, which could be zero even if it was set to one at some earlier point of time in the loop. I think you need to add a `break` statement after you set it to one the first time.

Comment: agreed with martineau. What about `if b.rect.collidepoint(p.rect.centerx,p.rect.bottom+4): grounded=1`? Doesn't the +4 force the player rectangle always to be above any valid block and therefore never inside it? Or does the player stand on the bottom of a block's coordinates?

Comment: I thought +4 would test a bit below the player, would it not?

Comment: @kobejohn `rect.bottom` is equivalent to `rect.top+rect.height`

Comment: @monkey I see. I misunderstood the pygame coordinate system. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my reading of your code, you have one `Player` in `players` and many `Blocks` in `instancelist`. Your inner loop is called for every `Block`-`Player` pair.  Unless you are lucky (or unlucky as this would hide a bug), the `Block` that the `Player` collides with will not be tha very last one you check.  Thus, in a later iteration of your loops, the `Block` you check will not collide with the `Player` and `grounded` will be set back to `0` in the `else` clause.

One solution might be to get rid of your `else` statement.  Thus, if any `Block` collides with the `Player`, grounded will be set to `1` and if no `Blocks` collide with the `Player`, `grounded` will simply remain at `0`.  If a `Block` collides, later `Blocks` that do not will not change the value of `grounded`.

```
while True:
    grounded = 0
    for b in instancelist:
        for p in players:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(p.rect.centerx,p.rect.bottom+4):
                grounded=1
    print grounded
```

A better solution might use a `break` statement to avoid unnecessary work.

```
while True:
    grounded = 0
    for p in players:
        for b in instancelist:
            if b.rect.collidepoint(p.rect.centerx,p.rect.bottom+4):
                grounded=1
                break
    print grounded
```

Comment: Your `break` method worked perfectly! :) Thanks a bunch A.E Drew!

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, as martineau said, the grounded loop is going to reset any discovery of grounding.

The instancelist seems like it would benefit from being a positional dict or array that you could more efficiently test based on the player's position rather than comparing the player's position to every block every time.

---

*edit - ignore below. @monkey kindly pointed out how I had inverted the pygame coordinate system.

Additionally, my reading of the docs suggests that your code is checking whether a given point resides within b.rect. The given point is the player's horizontal center and 4 above the player's bottom. If the player rests on the bottom of the block, then fine since it looks like it's size 16. But your fall code looks like it's going to send the player to -4 before it collides with the block? Anyway, you might want to reverse that to `-4` and see if it behaves more like what you want.

Comment: @A.E Drew's method fixed the problem, and +4 was correct.. but how could I make the array into a dict? That sounds like it would greatly improve performance.

Comment: That is probably more appropriate for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or at least a separate question on SO. Link it here with @kobejohn and I'll pick it up if I get time for it.

Comment: Ok @kobejohn! I'll throw it onto CodeReview!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32718/pygame-using-a-dict-to-store-objects-instead-of-an-array